# my rehashing is not working properly (full insert works but when the inserted values become half of total values i do rehash and it stops)

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

(Code below)
When I suppose I initialized the hashtable at 5000 for total max values.

While inserting I made that if the total values I inserted becomes half of max values it calls rehash(); but my program is crashing if it do rehash.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int getNextPrimeNum(int);

class Node{
    public:

    string key;
    int value; // ekhane mainly array index bujai
    Node* next;

    Node(string key, int value){
        this->key= key;
        this->value= value;
        this->next= NULL;
    }

};


class HashTable{
    public:
    vector<Node*> HashNodes;
    int collisions;
    int probes;
    string method;
    int maxHashValues;
    int currentHashValues;
    vector<bool>assigned;
    int hashF;
    
    //ekhane 3 ta method Custom probing, Double hashing, Separate chaining
    HashTable(string method, int hashvalues, int hashF ){
        this->maxHashValues= hashvalues;
        this->method= method;
        this->hashF= hashF;

        HashNodes.resize(maxHashValues);

        collisions=0;
        probes=0;
        this->currentHashValues=0;
        assigned.resize(maxHashValues, false);// hashfunction er value assigned ache kina dekhar jonno
    }
    void setProbe(int probe){
        probes=probe;
    }
    int getProbe(){
        return probes;
    }
    int getCollision(){
        return collisions;
    }

    int HashFunction1(string key){
        int hash = 0;
        int n = maxHashValues;

        for(int i = 0; i<key.length();  i++){
            hash = 37*hash+key[i];
        }
        hash %= n;
        if(hash<0){
            hash += n;
        }
        return hash;
    }
    int HashFunction2(string key){
        unsigned int n = maxHashValues;
        int hash = 0;
        for (char c : key){
            hash = (hash ^ ((c - 'a' + 1) + (hash<<5) + (hash>>2) ))%n;
        }
        if(hash<0){
            hash+=maxHashValues;
        }
        return hash%n ;

    }

    int auxHashFunction(string key){
        int hash = 1;
        int n = maxHashValues;
        for(int i = 0; i<key.length();  i++){
            hash = ((hash*37) + ((int)key[i]))%n;
        }
        hash =(hash*10 + 1)% maxHashValues;
        if(hash<0) hash += maxHashValues;
        return hash;
    }

    void rehash(){
        int oldMaxHashValues = maxHashValues;
        maxHashValues = (2*maxHashValues);
        vector<Node*> oldHashNodes = HashNodes;
    
        // Resize the hash table and reset the assigned vector
        for(int i=0; i<HashNodes.size(); i++){
            HashNodes[i]=NULL;
        }
        assigned.resize(maxHashValues, false);
        currentHashValues = 0;
    
        // Rehash all the existing elements
        for (int i = 0; i < oldMaxHashValues; i++) {
            Node* node = oldHashNodes[i];
            string str= node->key;
            Insert(str);
        }
    }
    
    //hashfunction 1 naki 2 deya lagbe
    void Insert(string key){
        
        int hashfuncValue;
        if(currentHashValues== maxHashValues/2){
            rehash();
        }

        if(method=="sep_chain"){

            if(hashF==1){
                hashfuncValue=HashFunction1(key);
            }else{
                hashfuncValue=HashFunction2(key);
            }

            if(assigned[hashfuncValue]==true){
                collisions++;
            }
            Node* newNode=new Node(key, hashfuncValue);

            if(HashNodes[hashfuncValue]==NULL){
                HashNodes[hashfuncValue]=newNode;
                currentHashValues++;
                assigned[hashfuncValue]=true;
            }else{
                newNode->next=HashNodes[hashfuncValue];
                HashNodes[hashfuncValue]=newNode;
                currentHashValues++;
                assigned[hashfuncValue]=true;
            }

        }
        else if(method=="double_hash"){
            if(hashF==1){
                hashfuncValue=HashFunction1(key);
            }else{
                hashfuncValue=HashFunction2(key);
            }

            if(assigned[hashfuncValue]==true){
                collisions++;
            }
            //we have to implement this doubleHash(k, i) = (Hash(k) + i × auxHash(k)) % N

            Node* newNode=new Node(key, hashfuncValue);
            if(HashNodes[hashfuncValue]==NULL){
                HashNodes[hashfuncValue]=newNode;
                currentHashValues++;
                assigned[hashfuncValue]=true;
            }
            else{
                int auxhashvalue= auxHashFunction(key);
                int doubleHash = hashfuncValue;
                int i=0;
                while(true){
                    if(i== maxHashValues) break;
                    if(HashNodes[doubleHash]==NULL){
                        HashNodes[doubleHash]=newNode;
                        currentHashValues++;
                        assigned[doubleHash]=true;
                        break;
                    }
                   //doubleHash(k, i) = (Hash(k) + i × auxHash(k)) % N
                   doubleHash= (hashfuncValue + (i*auxhashvalue))%maxHashValues;
                   collisions++;
                   i++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(method=="cus_prob"){
            //customHash(k, i) = (Hash(k) + C1 × i × auxHash(k) + C2 × i2) % N
            if(hashF==1){
                hashfuncValue=HashFunction1(key);
            }else{
                hashfuncValue=HashFunction2(key);
            }
            if(assigned[hashfuncValue]==true){
                collisions++;
            }

            Node* newNode=new Node(key, hashfuncValue);
            if(HashNodes[hashfuncValue]==NULL){
                HashNodes[hashfuncValue]=newNode;
                currentHashValues++;
                assigned[hashfuncValue]=true;
            }else{
                int c1=10, c2=5;
                int auxhashvalue= auxHashFunction(key);
                int customHash = hashfuncValue;
                int i=0;
                while(true){
                    if(i== maxHashValues)break;

                    if(HashNodes[customHash]==NULL){
                        HashNodes[customHash]=newNode;
                        currentHashValues++;
                        assigned[customHash]=true;
                        break;
                    }
                   //customHash(k, i) = (Hash(k) + C1 × i × auxHash(k) + C2 × i2) % N
                   customHash= (hashfuncValue + (c1 * i*auxhashvalue) + (c2* i* i)) % maxHashValues;
                   collisions++;
                   i++;
                }

            }
        }
      // insert  finish
    }
};

int main(){}
```

I am expecting the rehash would work properly

Comment: I see `assigned.resize()`: what about `HashNodes`?